# Is there any valid reason to install Tigerbrew (Homebrew) on a modern Mac OS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, leopard, powerpc

Perhaps you may be thinking that I'm asking why one *should* install Tigerbrew on their older PowerPC/Intel mac machine running Tiger or Leopard operating systems.

But I'm actually wondering if there's any reason to install it onto a modern Intel mac machine.

I'm running a Macbook Pro 2012 with El Capitan 10.11.6, and for some reason which I do not understand, when I type the command `man brew` in Terminal.app, I find the following:

```
       Tigerbrew  is  the  easiest  and  most flexible way to install the UNIX
       tools Apple didn't include with OS X.
```

Is there any reason why I would have Tigerbrew and not regular Homebrew? Did I download this in error?

###### I'm more inclined to think that I was just curious and had no reason, rather than something less likely, like I was hacked...somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to assume that you were not hacked by someone who then installed Tigerbrew on your computer.

Comment: Unless.....*dons conspiracy dunce cap*....Tigerbrew has a flaw that allows it to be a vector for executing malicious code?

Comment: If they can access your Mac to install Tigerbrew, I'm sure there are then better options for them than Tigerbrew. But believe what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From [mistydemeo](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew): Tigerbrew is "A little experimental fork of Homebrew that adds support for PowerPC Macs, and Macs running Tiger (or Leopard)."

So, on the face of it there is no reason to install Tigerbrew on a *modern* macOS. In fact, there are good reasons to remove it.

But:

1. You don't have a modern macOS and the real [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is fully supported on 10.14 onwards and only best effort on 10.9-10.13
2. Homebrew's installation instructions say "For 32-bit or PPC support see Tigerbrew".

So that gives 2 reasons for you to use Tigerbrew:

1. Homebrew's lack of full support for your version of macOS though it probably would work fine for installing basic unix utilities.  On the other hand, Tigerbrew is not intended for more recent than Leopard.
2. You particularly want to install old 32-bit brews.

But, if it were me, I would uninstall Tigerbrew (following instructions [from here](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) ) and install Homebrew. See how it goes for you.

Edit: According to current `man brew`, Misty De Meo is part of Homebrew's Project Leadership Committee. You could ask her via the [Tigerbrew GitHub](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) where you can find continuing interest on the [Issues](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew/issues) page.

Comment: Note, as someone who has done this, "only best effort" means "it doesn't work" basically all of the time. Do consider MacPorts if you're on one of those OS's, they put a ridiculous amount of effort into legacy support!

Comment: HA! "only best effort" is ~way~ over-selling it. The attitude is "if it works, great; if it doesn't, we don't support it and you're on your own. So, "best effort" here is more like "no effort" and even "don't post in our forums asking for help."